# Receiving error "Not a valid Python module" in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am struggling to get Python Tools working with Visual Studio. If I create a "Hello World" new application then it seems fine but if I try to import a script from github then I receive the error quoted below.

If I create a new project and then cut and paste the same script from github then there is no error.

If I then graft in the .git folder then it is still fine and git works. But after I close visual studio and open it again the next day the same error appears.

The error visual studio shows is:

> Not a valid Python module: C:\Users\David\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\example-project\example-project\example-project.py
>
> File: Microsoft.Python.Tools.Targets Line: 131

If I double click the error then it shows 15 warnings like these:

> Warning       The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
>   child element '_PythonToolsPath' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'Property, VisualStudioVersion,
>   MinimumVisualStudioVersion, AdditionalFileItemNames,
>   AllowUnsafeBlocks, AppConfigForCompiler, ApplicationIcon,
>   ApplicationRevision, ApplicationVersion, AppDesignerFolder,
>   AspNetConfiguration, AssemblyKeyContainerName,
>   AssemblyKeyProviderName, AssemblyName, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile,
>   AssemblyOriginatorKeyFileType, AssemblyOriginatorKeyMode,
>   AssemblyType, AutoGenerateBindingRedirects, AutorunEnabled,
>   BaseAddress, BootstrapperComponentsLocation,
>   BootstrapperComponentsUrl, BootstrapperEnabled, CharacterSet,
>   CheckForOverflowUnderflow, CLRSupport, UseDebugLibraries, CodePage,
>   Configuration, ConfigurationName, ConfigurationOverrideFile,
>   CreateDesktopShortcut, CreateWebPageOnPublish,
>   CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents, DebugSecurityZoneURL,
>   DebugSymbols, DebugType, DefaultClientScript, DefaultHTMLPageLayout,
>   DefaultTargetSchema, DefineConstants, DefineDebug, DefineTrace,
>   DelaySign, DisableLangXtns, DisallowUrlActivation,
>   CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions, CodeAnalysisApplyLogFileXsl, ....
>
> Project: Miscellaneous Files
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python
>   Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.targets
>
> Line: 15

All the other warnings look very similar with missing child elements.

I googled for this and found nothing. The only other clue is that on projects which work, next to the pythonscript.py file in the Solution Explorer it shows green PY but on the ones which produce the error I see a red tick and then the green PY letter/icon.

I failed to install Visual Studio the first 3 times due to low disk space. Could I have a broken installation or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug when the filename is converted into a importable module name, which is impossible when there is a hyphen in the name.

I just filed it on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/784).

Comment: This looks like the bug may now be fixed upstream (which is great) but I am unclear how to update an existing visual studio installation with this fix. Is this possible or does it require waiting for the next release? Are python scripts with hyphens in their names always going to be incompatible?

Comment: @DavidJames Look at the releases page for a dev build. Scripts with hyphens in the name will always be invalid module names (i.e. you can't `import` them), but they're valid script names.